# How to use multiple formgroup inside the form array

Tags: angular11

```
<div formArrayName="partners" style="margin-top:15px;" *ngIf="partner">
<div *ngFor="let partner of partners().controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="partner-background">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12">
                <h6 style="padding:5px;">Manage Partner <button id="remove" class="btn" style="float:right;" *ngIf="partners().length > 1 && i>0" (click)="removePartner(i)"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-1">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Full Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="p_first_name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div *ngFor="let type of types().controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;">
                        <div class="col col-3">
                            <label for="type" style="font-size:18px;">Type</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-4">
                            <div class="form-group form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="partner" formControlName="p_type" style="width:16px;height:16px;" value="urban">
                                <label class="form-check-label">Urban</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-4">
                            <div class="form-group form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="partner" formControlName="p_type" style="width:16px;height:16px;" value="rural">
                                <label class="form-check-label">Rural</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">DOB</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="p_dob">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Sex</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="p_sex"> -->
                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="p_sex">
                        <option value="" selected>Select sex</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Email</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="p_email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Phone No</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="p_phone">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you need to add multiple form controls inside one form group or multiple form controls inside the form array.

For checkbox, you need to add multiple form controls inside one formArray like this.

```
const arr = [this.fb.control(false), this.fb.control(false)];
fbArray =  this.fb.array(arr);
const form = this.fb.group({
    checkbox: fbArray,
});
```